# Data Transfer Between Options to Same Value and Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

There are two different select elements. These have equal value and text. There is also a radio button.
If the button with the same id is selected, I want to pass the value of the first option to the second. I wrote a jQuery code for this. However, instead of transferring, it creates a new text. I want the same value to be selected in the second one.
Although I searched for examples to solve the problem, I did not know exactly how to search. Therefore, I could not come to a conclusion.

**First option**

```
<select id='country-first'>
<option value='A01'>A</option>
<option value='A02'>B</option>
</select>
```

**Second option**

```
<select id='country-second'>
<option value='A01'>A</option>
<option value='A02'>B</option>
</select>
```

**Radio Button**

```
 Same country: <input type="radio" id="same" value="same">
 Different country: <input type="radio" id="different" value="diffent">
```

**jQuery Code**

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#same', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
           jQuery('#country-first').find(":selected").text(jQuery('#country-second').find(":selected").text());
   
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', '#same', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#country-first option[value='" + $("#country-second").val() + "']").prop("selected", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='country-first'>
  <option value='A01'>A</option>
  <option value='A02'>B</option>
</select>
<select id='country-second'>
  <option value='A01'>A</option>
  <option value='A02'>B</option>
</select>
Same country: <input type="radio" id="same" name="fav_language" value="HTML"> Different country: <input type="radio" id="different" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
```

Your script changes the text but does not adjust which option is selected. Using the proper Selector, you can then re-assign which Option is selected.

Comment: Thank you. A minor adjustment should be made. I'd appreciate it if you could change the ID's. Someone else can investigate this issue. Actually, I asked the opposite. That is, if radio is selected, the value in option-1 should be set to 2.